# How to return the most recent year from a table of data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a range of orders and I need to just display the most recent year a person has ordered. I have tried to chain some if functions together but that hasn't worked.

`=IF(OR(C3>0,G3>0,P3>0),G2,"")AND(if(OR(D3>0,H3>0,K3>0,Q3>0),H2,"")and(IF(OR(E3>0,I3>0,L3>0,R3>0),I2,"")))`

I am not sure if there is a simpler way to say if cells xyz>0 then g but if abc>0 then d.

I have also included a photo of the data set

[image: Data Set]

Comment: can you use MAXIFS which comes with 2016 and onwards?

Comment: Thank you that was much simpler

Comment: no probs, post your solution as an answer so others can make use of it too

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help everyone

---

=MAXIFS($C$2:$S$2,C11:S11,">0")

---

This returned the most recent year ordered in column U then I just used and index match on the other sheet I needed to display the information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
=MAX(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C3:S3))*1*(Sheet1!$C$2:$S$2))
```

which works on any page referencing any other page. Not CSE. It works with expansion for future years being inserted.

It is set for row by row evaluation. If the other page would have customers in a different order, one would need to get more complicated. `MATCH()` (massaged to adjust for the header rows) to locate the row, then that fed into `INDIRECT()` for the first range reference (the second reference never changes). And "no match" error handling would not be a terrible thing (="", presumably).